# How to insert data in the array (inside a loop)?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a problem with inserting data to the array. In the program I search all cells with "Data:" value. If this value appear I jump to the cell on the right and mark it. I want to collect all marked values (all of them are dates) in the array but with my code (enclosed below) I have an error. I have tried ReDim and setting an exact number of objects in the array. I would be grateful for a help.

```
Sub CheckData()
Dim FindIt As Range
Dim EndIt As Range
Dim StartAddress As String

With Range("A1:A100")
    Set EndIt = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With

Set FindIt = Range("A1:A100").Find(what:="Data:", after:=EndIt)

If Not FindIt Is Nothing Then
    StartAddress = FindIt.Address
End If

Dim Tabel() As Variant
Tabel = Array()
i = 0

Do Until FindIt Is Nothing
    Set FindIt = Range("A1:A100").FindNext(after:=FindIt)

    Data = FindIt.Address
    Range(Data).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

    'Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value
    Tabel(i) = ActiveCell.Value
    i = i + 1
    'Debug.Print i

    If FindIt.Address = StartAddress Then
        Exit Do
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What error, at what line?

Comment: Tabel(i) = ActiveCell.Value "Runtime-error   '9' subscript out of range"

Comment: Before using `Tabel`, you need to `ReDim` it: `ReDim Preserve Tabel(i)`

Answer (score 3):

You never sized your array.

```
Dim Tabel() As Variant
```

Use `ReDim` to resize a dynamically-sized array.

```
ReDim Preserve Tabel(0 To UBound(Tabel)+1)
```

However that's a terribly inefficient thing to do in a loop (you're copying the same elements over and over and over and over again, at every single iteration).

Rule of thumb, if you don't know from the start how many elements you're going to need, it's probably best to use a `Collection` instead of an array.

```
Dim items As Collection
Set items = New Collection

'...

items.Add ActiveCell.Value
```

Comment: Also, you skip your first "Data:" since your loop starts with `Set FindIt = Range("A1:A100").FindNext(after:=FindIt)` and you already found one `FindIt`, your array or collection will always start with the 2nd "Data:"

Comment: It is a first time when I try to find all records with an exact value. I know that I start with  the second search but I didn't know how to solve it so I check 1st row at the end and it is marked as well. If I didn't use "after:=
" it didn't work at all. Do you maybe know how to do it differently? I will be happy to learn more.:)

Comment: See @JasonBrady's answer for another valid (IMO more robust than `Find`) approach

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a for loop instead of a find (also using Mat's Mug idea about collections)

```
Sub CheckData1()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim searchRng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim tabel As Collection 'incorrectly spelt table?

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set tabel = New Collection
Set searchRng = ws.Range("A1:A100")

For Each cell In searchRng.Cells
    If cell.Value = "Data:" Then
        tabel.Add cell.Offset(, 1)
        cell.Offset(, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'If you still need it highlighted
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't need to alter the cells, it might be a good idea to dump the search range into a local variant array, and iterate *that* instead of `Range` objects, which are notoriously slow. Also if `cell.Value` contains an error (e.g. `#REF!`), expect a *type mismatch* on that `If` statement; you can avoid it by first checking whether `IsError(cell.Value)`.